# Integral over a product of polynomial, exponential and Bessel function

Tags: integration, special-functions, gamma-function, integral-transforms

In a physics textbook I'm working through I found an interesting integral identity which I want to prove:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty t^{\nu +1} J_\nu(\beta t) e^{-\alpha t} \, dt = \frac{2\alpha (2\beta)^\nu \Gamma(\nu + \tfrac{3}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi} (\alpha^2 + \beta^2)^{\nu + 3/2}}
\end{equation}
where $J_\nu$ is the Bessel function and $\Re(\nu)>-1, \Re(\alpha) > |\Im(\beta)|$. In my case for the application of this identity these conditions are always fulfilled since it will be $\alpha > 0, \beta \geq 0, \nu \geq 1/2$.

One could write this integral as the Hankel transform of the function $f(t) = t^\nu e^{-\alpha t}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}_\nu [f(t)](\beta) = \int_0^\infty f(t) J_\nu (\beta t) t \, dt \,.
\end{equation}
However this is more of an interesting fact about this integral and not helpful for the proof I assume. The result can perhaps be found in a table of Hankel transforms but I doubt it will be given alongside a proof.

My idea and calculations so far are the following. Using the series definition of the Bessel function and then switching summation and integration we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty t^{\nu +1} J_\nu(\beta t) e^{-\alpha t} \, dt &= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(\nu+m+1)} \int_0^\infty t^{\nu+1} \left( \frac{\beta t}{2} \right)^{2m+\nu} e^{-\alpha t} \, dt \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(\nu+m+1)} \left( \frac{\beta}{2} \right)^{2m+\nu} \int_0^\infty t^{2(m+\nu)+1} e^{-\alpha t} \, dt \,.
\end{align}
Using the integral identity
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-ax} \, dx = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{a^{n+1}}
\end{equation}
we can write this as
\begin{equation}
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(\nu+m+1)} \left( \frac{\beta}{2} \right)^{2m+\nu} \frac{\Gamma(2(m+\nu+1))}{\alpha^{2(m+\nu+1)}} \,.
\end{equation}
Now my idea was to use the duplication formula for the Gamma function
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z+\tfrac{1}{2}) = 2^{1-2z} \sqrt{\pi} \, \Gamma(2z)
\end{equation}
which leads to
\begin{gather}
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m! \Gamma(\nu+m+1)} \left( \frac{\beta}{2} \right)^{2m+\nu} \frac{\Gamma(\nu+m+1) \Gamma(\nu+m+\tfrac{3}{2})}{2^{1-2(m+\nu+1)} \sqrt{\pi} \, \alpha^{2(m+\nu+1)}} \\
= \frac{2^{\nu+1} \beta^\nu}{\sqrt{\pi} \alpha^{2(\nu+1)}} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!} \left( \frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2} \right)^m \Gamma(\nu+m+\tfrac{3}{2}) \,.
\end{gather}
I hope that I made no mistake while simplifying the expression. Now I'm stuck at the evaluation of the sum. So far I see not much resemblance to the desired result.

Using this approach I was able to show that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty t^{\nu +1} J_\nu(\beta t) e^{-\alpha t^2} \, dt = \frac{\beta^\nu}{(2\alpha)^{\nu+1}} \exp{(\tfrac{-\beta^2}{4\alpha})}
\end{equation}
quite easily, so I think this way would work here too. I would be thankful for any input on how to proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've done most of the work! Using the fact that $$\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$$
we get: $$\Gamma\left(\nu+m+\frac 3 2\right)=\left(\nu+\frac 3 2\right)\left(\nu+\frac 5 2\right)\dots\left(\nu+m+\frac 1 2\right)\Gamma\left(\nu+\frac 3 2\right)$$
Replacing in your sum:
$$\begin{split}
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!} \left( \frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2} \right)^m \Gamma(\nu+m+\tfrac{3}{2}) &= \Gamma(\nu+\tfrac{3}{2})\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m\left(\nu+\frac 3 2\right)\dots\left(\nu+m+\frac 1 2\right)}{m!} \left( \frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2} \right)^m \\
&= \Gamma(\nu+\tfrac{3}{2})\left( 1+\frac {\beta^2}{\alpha^2}\right)^{-\nu-\frac 3 2}
\end{split}$$
where we have used the well-known [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

This should give you the result you wanted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. How did I not notice the fundamental property of the Gamma function? Shame on me :D But certainly I would not have seen the resemblance to the binomial series. I like the simplicity of this solution.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't be harsh on yourself. It's sometimes easy to forget some of those identities.

Answer (score 4):

To use that approach we need the additional restriction $|\beta| < |\alpha|$ so that the series converges.

The hypergeometric representation of $(1-z)^{-a}$ is $_{1}F_{0}(a;;z)$.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#The_series_1F0) for an explanation.

Therefore,  $$ \begin{align} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!} \left( \frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2} \right)^m \Gamma\left(\nu+m+\frac{3}{2}\right) &=  \Gamma \left(\nu + \frac{3}{2} \right) \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!} \left( \frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2} \right)^m \frac{\Gamma(\nu+m+\tfrac{3}{2})}{\Gamma\left(\nu+\tfrac{3}{2}\right)} \\ &= \Gamma \left(\nu + \frac{3}{2} \right) \, _{1}F_{0} \left(\nu + \frac{3}{2}; ; - \frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}} \right) \\ &= \Gamma \left(\nu + \frac{3}{2} \right) \left(1+ \frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}} \right)^{-\nu-3/2}, \end{align}$$

and $$\begin{align} \frac{2^{\nu+1} \beta^\nu}{\sqrt{\pi} \alpha^{2(\nu+1)}} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!} \left( \frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2} \right)^m \Gamma\left(\nu+m+\frac{3}{2}\right) &=  \frac{2^{\nu+1} \beta^\nu}{\sqrt{\pi} \alpha^{2(\nu+1)}}\Gamma \left(\nu + \frac{3}{2} \right) \left(1+ \frac{\beta^{2}}{\alpha^{2}} \right)^{-\nu-3/2}  \\ &= \frac{2^{\nu+1} \beta^\nu}{\sqrt{\pi} \alpha^{2(\nu+1)}} \frac{\alpha^{2\nu+3} \,  \Gamma \left(\nu + \tfrac{3}{2} \right)}{\left(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2} \right)^{\nu+3/2}}\\ &= \frac{2\alpha (2\beta)^\nu \, \Gamma(\nu + \tfrac{3}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi} (\alpha^2 + \beta^2)^{\nu + 3/2}}. \end{align}
$$

---

The integral $$\int_0^\infty t^{\nu} J_{\nu}(\beta t) e^{-\alpha t} \, \mathrm dt $$ has a simple closed-form expression as well, which we can find using the [formula for the Laplace transform of $\frac{f(t)}{t}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_improper_integrals).

Assume that $\Re(\nu) >- \frac{1}{2} $.

Then

$$ \begin{align} \int_0^\infty t^{\nu} J_\nu(\beta t) e^{-\alpha t} \, \mathrm dt &= \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{\nu+1} J_\nu(\beta t)}{t}  e^{-\alpha t} \, \mathrm dt \\ &= \frac{(2 \beta)^{\mu} \, \Gamma \left(\nu + \tfrac{3}{2} \right)}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{\alpha}^{\infty} \frac{2 p}{(p^2 + \beta^2)^{\nu + 3/2}} \, \mathrm dp \\ &=  \frac{(2 \beta)^{\nu} \, \Gamma \left(\nu + \tfrac{3}{2} \right)}{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{1}{\nu + \tfrac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2})^{\nu+1/2}} \\ &= \frac{(2 \beta)^{\nu} \, \Gamma \left(\nu + \frac{1}{2} \right)}{\sqrt{\pi} (\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2})^{\nu+ 1/2}}. \end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer and the useful reference. I don't know much about the hypergeometric function (yet). It is certainly a very interisting and useful tool!